# How to find out which button was clicked in handler function

Tags: javascript

In my code, I need to make it so when button 1 is pressed it sets a number to be "1" and if button 2 is pressed, it sets the number to be 2.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <table style="width:65%;height:100px">
    <tr><td align="center" id="blockOne">
    <p><button onclick="addGraph()" id="buttonOne">Create Graph/Chart</button></p>
    <tr><td align="center" id="blockTwo">
    <p><button onclick="addGraph()"id ="buttonTwo">Create Graph/Chart</button></p>
  </table>
</body>
<script>
    var button1 = document.getElementById('buttonOne');
    var button2 = document.getElementById('buttonTwo');
    var container = "0";

    // When the user clicks the button, open the modal
    function addGraph() {
    {
        if (button1.onclick === true)  {
            container = "1";
        }
        if (button2.onclick === true) {
            container = "2";
        }
    }
        console.log(container);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a test question?

Comment: A test question?

Comment: `button.onclick` isn't true or false depending on whether the button was clicked. You set it to an anonymous function that calls `addGraph()`. Also note that your question isn't about setting a variable, it's about finding out which button was clicked when multiple buttons are handled by the same function.

Comment: @JoshGoldsmith Looking at your past questions, you are a serial abuser of this website. Stop opening a question for every tiny little issue. Ignore the fact that vampire feeders are helping you and learn how to find out stuff on your own. You are making trivial beginner's mistakes, you don't do nearly enough research and you also ask "how to" questions, which usually do not belong on here. This isn't yahoo answers.

Comment: @ChrisG I do research on the topic and attempt the problem myself, if I can't figure out how to do it on my own, I got to this website for other peoples inputs. I learn better when I see how other people have done things then apply that new knowledge to my own code.

Comment: @JoshGoldsmith I get all that, but stack overflow is a special site with strict rules. What you really need is tutoring and more practice. The goal of stack overflow is to build a repository of questions and answers, an all-encompassing FAQ if you will. Your question is off-topic, plain and simple.

Comment: Your question demonstrates that you don't realize that `button1.onclick` was set to `function() { addGraph() }`, despite having explicitly stated so in your HTML. This means it is too early to post here. Don't take it personally, the JavaScript tag in general has far more OT questions like this than proper ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass a parameter in your `addGraph` function which can be assigned to `container` as `button1.onclick` is not a valid way that gives you a boolean result.

```js
var button1 = document.getElementById('buttonOne');
var button2 = document.getElementById('buttonTwo');
var container = "0";

function addGraph(value) {
  container = value;
  console.log(container);
}
```

```html
<table border='1' style="width:65%;height:100px">
  <tr><td align="center" id="blockOne">
  <p><button onclick="addGraph(1)" id="buttonOne">Create Graph/Chart</button></p></tr>
  <tr><td align="center" id="blockTwo">
  <p><button onclick="addGraph(2)"id ="buttonTwo">Create Graph/Chart</button></p></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If i were to then run a function depending on the results, would it look something like this?   function generateBar() {

    if (container.value === "1") {
    }
    else if (container.value === "2") {
    }

Answer (score 2):

You can check which button was pressed by passing `this` as your function parameter.

Then, simply check your element's id and edit `container` with :

```
container = elem.id == 'buttonOne' ? "1" : "2";
```

```js
var container = "0";

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal
function addGraph(elem) {
  container = elem.id == 'buttonOne' ? "1" : "2";
  console.log(container);
}
```

```html
<table style="width:65%;height:100px">
  <tr>
    <td align="center" id="blockOne">
      <p><button onclick="addGraph(this)" id="buttonOne">Create Graph/Chart</button></p>
      <tr>
        <td align="center" id="blockTwo">
          <p><button onclick="addGraph(this)" id="buttonTwo">Create Graph/Chart</button></p>
</table>
```

Comment: Or use `e.target`

Comment: If I were to add 2 more buttons, would I just change it to this "container = elem.id == 'buttonOne' ? "1" : "2" : "3" : "4";"

Comment: @JoshGoldsmith If you want to add more buttons, just use a `switch case` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the function to accept the number as input, and make the onclick function called filled with the dedicated number.

```
<button onclick="addGraph(1)">Some text</button>
```

In this case you don't even need to define the button id, if you don't need to manipulate the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that in your Html you should open and close all the html elements.

In your JavaScript logic you can select multiple elements by their `id`s with `document.querySelectorAll('#buttonOne, #buttonTwo')`

Than just iterate over all them with [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to dynamically attach the click event listener and handle the container value like this `container = (index + 1).toString();`

Code:

```js
let container = '0';
document
  .querySelectorAll('#buttonOne, #buttonTwo')
  .forEach((el, index) => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    container = (index + 1).toString();
    console.log(container);
  }));
```

```html
<table style="width:65%;height:100px">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <p>
        <button id="buttonOne">Create Graph/Chart</button>   
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <p>
        <button id="buttonTwo">Create Graph/Chart</button>
      </p>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```